# Filling the bars in stacked bar plots with hash or dot points

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I was looking for a way to fill the bars in bar plots or stacked bar plots with hashes or dots (something like the following figure).

[image]

Since it took me a long time to figure it out how to do it, I share my finding here as an answer, maybe it is useful for someone else.

Comment: Nice. You can answer your own question.

Comment: Do you mean I should remove the second part from question, and it as answer?

Answer (score 7):

The key to solving the problem is using the **pattern** package which is introduced in the [PGF manual](http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar stacked]
\addplot [draw=blue,pattern=horizontal lines light blue] coordinates {(1,1)  (2,3) (3,2)};
\addplot [draw=red, pattern color = green, pattern = north west lines] coordinates {(1,1)  (2,1) (3,1)};
\addplot [pattern = dots] coordinates {(1,1)  (2,1) (3,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]